# what is the difference between no-loop and lock-on-active in drools

Tags: drools

Here is an example of a rule that uses "no-loop":

```
rule "Even Number Rule"   
dialect "java"  
no-loop  
      when  
       n : Number( number !=0 && (number%2)==0 , value : number)  
    then  
        modify(n){setNumber(8)};  
      end
```

Answer (score 44):

Long story short:

- no-loop: avoid the re-activation of a rule caused by the RHS of that SAME rule.
- lock-on-active: avoid the re-activation of a rule NO MATTER what the cause is.

Long story: http://ilesteban.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/about-drools-and-infinite-execution-loops/

Hope it helps,

Comment: There's a lot of other answers to this same question, but this one explains it best.