# how to change drools object status when execute rules

Tags: java, drools

Drools object not updated when execute .

I try to change drools fact in the process of executing rules, however, even I use update(), the object's attribute does not updated in LHS.

(1) I create a new object like: 
Person p=new Person(8,"female");

(2)  I assume when though rule_1, this person's gender will change to "male"

```
rule "rule_1"
salience 1
lock-on-active true
when
   $person : Person (age < 10)
then
    $person.gender = "male";
    update($person);
end

rule "rule_2"
salience 1
lock-on-active true
when
   $person : Person (gender == "male" )
then
    System.out.println($person.gender);
    update($person);
end
```

rule_2 does not execute. Does anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `lock-on-active` attribute you are using. It is basically preventing new activations of rules while you are executing them.

This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042437/what-is-the-difference-between-no-loop-and-lock-on-active-in-drools/17049887#17049887) explains a little bit better the way `lock-on-active` works.

Hope it helps,