# how to stop looping in drools rule?

Tags: drools

I am using guided rule in business central, Modiying the fact in action part with no-loop true .
Still the looping is happening .
when I use lock-on-active the rule do not run at all.
Please help.

```
rule "today true and close time is before 15pm"
    dialect "mvel"
    salience 120
    ruleflow-group "gogo"
    no-loop true
    lock-on-active true
when
    v : VendorWorkingDays( eval( vendorWD contains(java.time.LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).getDayOfWeek().toString()) )&& todayFlag == true && eval( closeTime.isBefore(java.time.LocalTime.parse("15:00:00")) ))
then
    modify( v ) {
        setTodayOneE( "NA" ),
        setTodayOneM( "Available" ), 
        setTodayOneFlag( true )
    }
    System.out.println("today true and close time is before 15pm");
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at this other question: [what is the difference between no-loop and lock-on-active in drools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042437/what-is-the-difference-between-no-loop-and-lock-on-active-in-drools/17049887#17049887)

In your case, the use of `modify` is causing the rules related to the `VendorWorkingDays` to be re-evaluated. The use of `no-loop` only works for when you have a single rule looping. I guess that in your case, you may have multiple rules involved in the infinite loop.
The use of `lock-on-active` will prevent the execution of this rule if the `VendorWorkingDays` is being inserted into the session (or modified) from another rule.

There is a link to a blog post in the question I mentioned that will give you a better explanation about these two attributes (the blog post is quite old, but the principles are still more or less valid for the latest version of Drools).

Comment: When I use lock-on-active the rule do not run at all. 
The same rule is looping even though no loop is true.
Is the any way to execute the rules only once.